# Highlight (select) a bar in a holoviews bars chart

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, holoviews

Consider the following minimal example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv

hv.extension('bokeh')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Cat": ["foo", "bar", "hello", "world"],
    "Values": [1, 3, 2, 4]
})

bars = hv.Bars(df)
bars
```

This yields:

[image]

**My question is how can I highlight one of the bars?**

Based on the hints in [the docs](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Indexing_and_Selecting_Data.html) I tried something like:

```py
bars = hv.Bars(df)
highlight_bar = bars[2:3]
bars * highlight_bar
```

But this returned an error `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`. I failed to workaround this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer *is* in the manual...

```py
bars = hv.Bars(df)
highlight_bar = bars.iloc[2:3]
bars * highlight_bar
```